# Process String name to use as Pshape in a loop

Tags: processing

I am trying to pull a sting variable and place it in a shape function so that the correct state will appear. I have a single (hard-coded) version working but am trying to make the code efficient and more dynamic by adding a loop.

See the code below:

```java
PShape usa;

PShape Alabama;
PShape Alaska;
PShape Arizona;
PShape Arkansas;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);  
  usa = loadShape("map.svg");

  Alabama= usa.getChild("AL");
  Alaska= usa.getChild("AK");
  Arizona= usa.getChild("AZ");
  Arkansas= usa.getChild("AR");
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  Table table = loadTable("data.csv", "header");
  for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {

    // Gets the 1st (then 2nd, then 3rd...) TABLE ROW
    TableRow row = table.getRow(i);

    //  Gets the data values and places in variables
    String state = row.getString("state");
    String state_abv = row.getString("state_abv");
    float percentage = row.getFloat("percentage");


    // Draw the full map
    shape(usa, 0, 0);

    //*****************************
    // THIS IS THE DYNAMIC ATTEMPT
    state.disableStyle();
    fill(0);
    shape(state, 0, 0);
    text(state_abv, 100 100);
    text(percentage, 100 150);


    // THIS WORKS BUT IS A SINGLE STATE AND HARD CODE...
    // NewJersey.disableStyle();
    // fill(R, 255, 255);
    // shape(NewJersey, 0, 0);

    // DATA FILE IS LIKE SO:
    // state, state_abv,percentage
    /*
     Alabama,AL,21.5
     Alaska,AK,19
     Arizona,AZ,14.7
     Arkansas,AR,23.6
     */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, it sounds like you're looking for the `HashMap` class. Similar to how an array maps an index (0, 1, 2, 3...) to a value, a `HashMap` maps any object (including a `String` like `"PA"`, `"VA"`, `"CA"`...) to a value. Here's a basic example:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("PA", "Harrisburg");
map.put("VA", "Richmond");
map.put("CA", "Sacramento");
String city = map.get("VA");
println(city);
```

This example maps `String` keys to `String` values, but you can use any object as a key or value. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

If you still can't get it figured out, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: I will try this - In the meantime, I have pasted a solution below - although now my problem is with the FILL COLOR...

Comment: @NetTemple If you have follow-up questions, please post them in their own new question posts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, although the FILL COLOR issue is still not resolved... (which is a separate issue). But this does put all of the DATA from the external data file and places into a functioning array "states[]"

```
PShape usa;
PShape[] states;       // array to hold all states
int numstates;         //count number of states

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);

  //load the map
  usa = loadShape("map.svg");
  parseMap();          
  smooth();
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  background(200);
  drawMap();
}

// ***** ------------------------
// ***** ----- PARSE MAP
// ***** ------------------------
void parseMap() {
  numstates = usa.getChildCount(); //count number of child shapes on map
  states = new PShape[numstates];
  //println("NUMSTATES " + numstates);

  // stateCodes = new String[numstates];
  usa.disableStyle(); //turn off styles for whole map

  //make state objects
  for (int i = 0; i < numstates; i++) {
    states[i] = usa.getChild(i);
    println("NUMSTATES " + states[i]);
  }
}


// ***** ------------------------
// ***** ----- DRAW MAP
// ***** ------------------------
void drawMap() {
  for (int n = 0; n < numstates; n++) {

    Table table = loadTable("data.csv", "header");
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {

      // Gets the 1st (then 2nd, then 3rd...) TABLE ROW
      TableRow row = table.getRow(i);

      //  Gets the data values and places in variables
      String s = row.getString("state");
      String a = row.getString("abv");
      float p = row.getFloat("percent");
      int colora = row.getInt("colora");
      int colorb = row.getInt("colorb");
      int colorc = row.getInt("colorc");
      int loca = row.getInt("loca");
      int locb = row.getInt("locb");

      states[n].disableStyle();
      // fill(colora,colorb,colorc);          // PROBLEM HERE: It fills ALL states same color
      states[n].fill(colora,colorb,colorc);   // I AM TRYING TO FILL EACH STATE A DIFFERNET COLOR
      stroke(255,0,0);
      strokeWeight(2);
      shape(states[n],0,0);
      fill(255);
      text(p, loca, locb);
    }
    println("NUMSTATES " + numstates);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post follow-up questions in their own question posts.